# pgfplots surf plot: don't draw 'NaN'

Tags: pgfplots, matlab2tikz

I generated a checkerboard style suface plot using matlab2tikz.
The data contains nan (not a number) values. I want the squares of nan values to be white (as in matlab). When I compile, I get the following warning:

> Package pgfplots Warning: The per point meta data `nan' (3Y0.0e0]) (and probabl
>   y others as well) is unbounded - using the minimum value instead. on input line
>    58.

and the square is filled with the colour for '0'. I tried to skip the nan values using

```
unbounded coords=discard
```

The warning and the behaviour stayed the same.
When removing the nan values, the square seems to take the color of its neighbour.

Here's the code generated by matlab2tikz:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.10}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{axis}[%
view={0}{90},
scale only axis,
xmin=1, xmax=5,ymin=1,ymax=5,zmin=-1,zmax=1,
hide axis,
colormap/jet,
colorbar,
point meta min=1,
point meta max=100
]

\addplot3[%
surf,
shader=flat corner,
draw=black,
colormap/jet,
point meta=explicit,
%unbounded coords=discard,
mesh/rows=5]
table[row sep=crcr,header=false,meta index=3] {
    1   1   0   1  \\
    1   2   0   10  \\
    1   3   0   20  \\
    1   4   0   30  \\
    1   5   0   1  \\
    2   1   0   40  \\
    2   2   0   nan  \\
    2   3   0   50  \\
    2   4   0   60   \\
    2   5   0   1  \\
    3   1   0   70  \\
    3   2   0   80  \\
    3   3   0   90   \\
    3   4   0   nan  \\
    3   5   0   1  \\
    4   1   0   75  \\
    4   2   0   80  \\
    4   3   0   85  \\
    4   4   0   100  \\
    4   5   0   1  \\
    5   1   0   1  \\
    5   2   0   1  \\
    5   3   0   1   \\
    5   4   0   1   \\
    5   5   0   1   \\
};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

And here the output:
[image]

Is there a way to not drawing the squares with nan values? Or to add a discrete color to the continuous colormap so that nan values are drawn in white?

Comment: I don't get warnings if I remove `compat=1.10` and put `compat=1.9`

Comment: That is strange, I still get the warning (and the same behaviour) when running with `compat=1.9`

Comment: Behavoiur is not good for me too, but no warning.

Comment: @HarishKumar: You didn't get the warning because i had no 'nan' value in the code above. Sry, my bad. I've edited the code and the output

Comment: I'll add a todo item for pgfplots. That sounds like missing support in the surf/mesh plot handler.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have found a quick n'dirty solution to the problem.

Instead of preventing nan fields from being drawn, I rendered them transparent.
To do so, I set opacity of the fields depending on the point meta data.
The opacity has to be = 0 for nan fields and >= 1 for other fields.

Therefore, the value of `point meta min` has to be slightly lower than the smallest point meta value (depending on the numerical resolution), so that `ceil(pgfplotspointmetatransformed)` >= 1 for the point with the smallest point meta.

The opacity is then set to `opacity = ceil(\pgfplotspointmetatransformed)`. (ceil has to be defined)
Since pgfplots sets all nan point meta values to `point meta min`, they appear transparent. Note that the border is not drawn for nan fields.

Here's the code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.10}
\begin{document}

\tikzset{
    declare function={Ceil(\x)=round(\x+0.49999);}
}

\begin{tikzpicture}

    \begin{axis}[%
        view={0}{90},
        scale only axis,
        xmin=1, xmax=5,ymin=1,ymax=5,zmin=-1,zmax=1,
        hide axis,
        colormap/jet,
        colorbar,
        point meta min=0.999999,
        point meta max=100
    ]

    \addplot3[%
        surf,
        shader=flat corner,
        draw=black,
        colormap/jet,
        point meta=explicit,
        opacity=Ceil(\pgfplotspointmetatransformed),
        mesh/rows=5
    ]
    table[row sep=crcr,header=false,meta index=3] {
        1   1   0   1  \\
        1   2   0   10  \\
        1   3   0   20  \\
        1   4   0   30  \\
        1   5   0   1  \\
        2   1   0   40  \\
        2   2   0   nan  \\
        2   3   0   50  \\
        2   4   0   60   \\
        2   5   0   1  \\
        3   1   0   70  \\
        3   2   0   80  \\
        3   3   0   90   \\
        3   4   0   nan  \\
        3   5   0   1  \\
        4   1   0   75  \\
        4   2   0   80  \\
        4   3   0   85  \\
        4   4   0   100  \\
        4   5   0   1  \\
        5   1   0   1  \\
        5   2   0   1  \\
        5   3   0   1   \\
        5   4   0   1   \\
        5   5   0   1   \\
};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

And here the output:
[image]

Comment: Late comment: As PGF has a `ceil` function already, you can remove the `declare function` and use `opacity=ceil(\pgfplotspointmetatransformed)` (looks like it gives the same result at least).

Answer (score 2):

I don't have an answer, but I'd also like this, for a simple scatter plot:

*(Example modified with the code suggested in the comment, it works!)*

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
\addplot[scatter,
         only marks,
         point meta=explicit,
         point meta min=0,
         unbounded coords=discard,
         filter point/.code={
           \pgfmathparse{\pgfkeysvalueof{/data point/meta}}
           \let\A=\pgfmathresult
           \pgfmathfloatgetflagstomacro\A\flags
           \ifnum\flags=3
             \pgfkeyssetvalue{/data point/x}{nan}
           \fi
         },
] table[row sep=crcr,header=false,meta index=2] {
1 1 20 \\
2 2 nan \\
3 3 50 \\
4 4 100 \\
};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I don't want the second point drawn at all (but I still want to have the coordinates there, as I want it to be drawn in in other `\addplot` commands).

Comment: While looking for a solution for my problem, I found one for yours: Put this filter after `unbounded coords=discard`:
`         filter point/.code={%
  \pgfmathparse
  {\pgfkeysvalueof{/data point/meta}}
  \let\A=\pgfmathresult
  \pgfmathfloatgetflagstomacro\A\flags
  \ifnum\flags=3
  \pgfkeyssetvalue{/data point/x}{nan}%
  \fi
  },`
It changes the x coordinate to nan if the meta data is nan. For more info on the filter: [pgfplots manual p.111 ](http://pgfplots.sourceforge.net/pgfplots.pdf).
More info on the `\pgfmathfloatgetflagstomacro` stuff here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/114310/21530

Comment: @vipers36 Thanks, it's included in my "reply" now.