# How to programmatically coax pgfplots to recognize nan within surface as matlab does

Tags: pgfplots, matlab, matlab2tikz

I came across [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/164250/pgfplots-surf-plot-dont-draw-nan?lq=1) post after wondering why nan's did not appear to be handled by pgfplots as they are by matlab when working with the matlab pcolor function.  My typical workflow in this context is:

1. create plot in matlab
2. call matlab2tikz
3. call a script which wraps the output of matlab2tikz such that it is compileable, write
   to file.
4. compile latex document which is output in above step (the preview environment so that a figure sized .pdf, with controllable border results).
5. place .pdf resulting from compilation at destination path.

At the moment, I'm wondering how to build the suggestions put forth in the post referenced above into my process (more or less fully automated).  The matlab2tikz options `extraCode`, `extraAxisOptions` and `extraTikzpictureOptions` seem relevant to me.

Tentatively, I would begin by trying something like this:

```
MATLAB2TIKZ('extraCode','\tikzset{declare function={Ceil(\x)=round(\x+0.49999);}}',...)
```

However, I am unaware of a mechanism to pass the code:

```
opacity=Ceil(\pgfplotspointmetatransformed)
```

as an option to the `\addplot3` command.

In summary, any suggestions/advice on how to implement the fix proposed in the linked post programmatically are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Normally you could skip step 3 by adding `'standalone',true` (if my memory serves me right, check the help) to `matlab2tikz`s options. However, I don't think you can add options to the `\addplot` via those options, so that probably needs to go into your script. Note that the `declare function` part isn't really necessary (see my comment to the accepted answer of the mentioned question).

Comment: Actually, looking at the `pgfplots` manual, you could try with `'extraAxisOptions','every axis plot post/.append style={opacity=ceil(\pgfplotspointmetatransformed)}'` added to `matlab2tikz`s options. If it works I can write up a proper answer later today.

Comment: @TorbjørnT, I used the matlab code: `EXTRACODE = {'\tikzset{declare function={Ceil(\x)=round(\x+0.49999);}}'};` and `EXTRAAXISOPTIONS = {'every axis plot post/.append style={opacity=ceil(\pgfplotspointmetatransformed)}'};` and the call was: `matlab2tikz(..., 'extraCode', EXTRACODE, 'extraAxisOptions', EXTRAAXISOPTIONS);`.  This worked on the first try; I now observe white where NaN's are present in the structure being plotted with pcolor.  I appreciate the help.

Comment: I note that the desired behavior is achieved with the `shading flat` rather than the `shading interp` matlab commands.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Short answer

Use

```
matlab2tikz('filename.tex','standalone',true,'extraAxisOptions','every axis plot post/.append style={opacity=ceil(\pgfplotspointmetatransformed),shader=flat corner}')
```

---

## Long answer

### Concerning point 3 on your list

Not related to the real problem, but worth mentioning: `matlab2tikz` can output a compilable file, by adding `'standalone',true` to the options. Use this, and you can skip the third step your list.

### Adding the opacity option

As you say, you can tell `matlab2tikz` to add additional options to the `axis` environment with the `'extraAxisOptions'` tag, used as

```
 matlab2tikz('figure.tex','extraAxisOptions','<list of options>');
```

Further, `pgfplots` has a style that applied to all plots, `every axis plot`, which you can use to add the opacity to the `\addplot`, i.e.

```
'extraAxisOptions','every axis plot post/.append style={opacity=ceil(\pgfplotspointmetatransformed)}'
```

Note that it is not necessary to add

```
\tikzset{
    declare function={Ceil(\x)=round(\x+0.49999);}
}
```

from [pgfplots surf plot: don't draw 'NaN'](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/164250/pgfplots-surf-plot-dont-draw-nan?lq=1), as PGF has a builtin `ceil` function. Also note that function names are case sensitive, so even if you define `Ceil`, it's not used if you write `ceil(\pgfplotspointmetatransformed)`.

Hence, the following call to `matlab2tikz` should take care of that part:

```
matlab2tikz('filename.tex','extraAxisOptions','every axis plot post/.append style={opacity=ceil(\pgfplotspointmetatransformed)}')
```

### Shader choice

As far as I can tell `pgfplots` should use  `shader=flat corner` for the `pcolor` plot to render properly, while `matlab2tikz` will use `shader=flat`, which is the same as `shader=flat mean` (see manual). For that reason, `shader=flat corner` should also be appended to the `every axis plot post`:

```
matlab2tikz('filename.tex','extraAxisOptions','every axis plot post/.append style={opacity=ceil(\pgfplotspointmetatransformed),shader=flat corner}')
```

### Problems with the smallest values

I cannot quite figure this out. `matlab2tikz` will usually set `point meta min` and `point meta max`, and in some cases at least this will set the opacity to cells where the value is equal to `point meta min` to 0 as well, see below code for example. As the `extraAxisOptions` are added *before* the `point meta min` by `matlab2tikz`, I'm not sure how to avoid such problems, other than manually editing the code, modifying the `point meta min` value, as mentioned in [pgfplots surf plot: don't draw 'NaN'](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/164250/).

#### Example code

```
[X,Y] = meshgrid(1:5,1:5);
Z = randi([2,100],5,5);
for j = 1:5
    % nans along diagonal
    Z(j,j) = nan;
end

% explicitly set one cell to 1
Z(2,3) = 1;

figure
pcolor(X,Y,Z)
colorbar


EXTRAAXISOPTIONS = {'every axis plot post/.append style={opacity=ceil(\pgfplotspointmetatransformed),shader=flat corner}'};
matlab2tikz('test.tex','standalone',true,'extraAxisOptions', EXTRAAXISOPTIONS);

% run pdflatex    
!pdflatex test.tex
% open pdf with gv (remove this line if that isn't installed)
!gv test.pdf&
```

#### Output

Matlab figure on left, PDF on right.

[image]

LaTeX code generated by the Matlab script above:

```
% This file was created by matlab2tikz v0.4.7 running on MATLAB 7.14.
% Copyright (c) 2008--2014, Nico Schlömer <nico.schloemer@gmail.com>
% All rights reserved.
% Minimal pgfplots version: 1.3
% 
% The latest updates can be retrieved from
%   http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/22022-matlab2tikz
% where you can also make suggestions and rate matlab2tikz.
% 
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{grffile}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usetikzlibrary{plotmarks}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{axis}[%
width=3.68666666666667in,
height=3.47733333333333in,
view={0}{90},
scale only axis,
xmin=1,
xmax=5,
ymin=1,
ymax=5,
zmin=-1,
zmax=1,
every axis plot post/.append style={opacity=ceil(\pgfplotspointmetatransformed),shader=flat corner},
colormap/jet,
colorbar,
point meta min=1,
point meta max=99
]

\addplot3[%
surf,
shader=flat corner,
draw=black,
colormap/jet,
point meta=explicit,
mesh/rows=5]
table[row sep=crcr,header=false,meta index=3] {1    1   0   nan\\
1   2   0   60\\
1   3   0   26\\
1   4   0   67\\
1   5   0   10\\
2   1   0   63\\
2   2   0   nan\\
2   3   0   74\\
2   4   0   90\\
2   5   0   99\\
3   1   0   78\\
3   2   0   1\\
3   3   0   nan\\
3   4   0   59\\
3   5   0   3\\
4   1   0   13\\
4   2   0   87\\
4   3   0   49\\
4   4   0   nan\\
4   5   0   22\\
5   1   0   56\\
5   2   0   64\\
5   3   0   5\\
5   4   0   62\\
5   5   0   nan\\
};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}%
\end{document}
```

If you modify line 34 to read `point meta min=0.999` the output is instead

[image]