# Conditional nodes near coords in pgfplots

Tags: pgfplots, pgfmath

I have a `matrix plot` with `nan` meta values. Now I want to print only the `nodes near coords` which are not `nan` but somehow I cannot figure out how to do that.

Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\pgfplotsset{width=7cm,compat=1.18}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[enlargelimits=false,
point meta rel=per plot, 
nodes near coords={%
    \ifthenelse{\expandafter\equal{\pgfmathprintnumber\pgfplotspointmeta}{NaN}}{}{\pgfmathprintnumber\pgfplotspointmeta}}]
\addplot [matrix plot,
point meta=explicit,
] coordinates {
(0,0) [0] (1,0) [1] (2,0) [2]

(0,1) [nan] (1,1) [nan] (2,1) [nan]

};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: You can probably test against the flag: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/114310/47927

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expanding on [this great answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/114310/47927), you could text against the flag of the relevant value:

```
\documentclass[border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{width=7cm, compat=1.18}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    enlargelimits=false,
    point meta rel=per plot, 
    nodes near coords={%
        \pgfmathfloatparsenumber{\pgfplotspointmeta}
        \pgfmathfloatgetflagstomacro\pgfmathresult\currentflags
        \ifnum\currentflags=3\else
            \pgfmathprintnumber\pgfplotspointmeta
        \fi
    }
]
\addplot[
    matrix plot,
    point meta=explicit,
] coordinates {
    (0,0) [0] (1,0) [1] (2,0) [2]
    
    (0,1) [nan] (1,1) [nan] (2,1) [nan]
};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Wow, thank you so much!